# Transforming an RDD to DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark

Hi i am new to Spark and i am trying to  transform an rdd to dataframe.The rdd is a folder with many  .txt files in it, and each one of them have a paragraph of text.Assume my rdd is this

```
val data = sc.textFile("data")
```

I would like to transform the data to a dataframe like this

```
  +------------+------+
  |text        | code |  
  +----+-------+------|
  |data of txt1|  1.0 |
  |data of txt2|  1.0 |
```

So the column "text" should have the raw data of each txt file and the column "code" 1.0
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you even try to look at the documentation?

Answer (score 4):

```
val data = sc.textFile("data.txt")

*// The schema is encoded in a string* 
val schemaString = "text code"

*// Import Row.*
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;

*// Import Spark SQL data types*
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType,StructField,StringType};

*// Generate the schema based on the string of schema*
val schema = StructType( schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))

*// Convert records of the RDD (data) to Rows.*
val rowRDD = data.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Row(p(0), p(1).trim))

*// Apply the schema to the RDD.*
val dataDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)

*// Register the DataFrames as a table.*
dataDataFrame.registerTempTable("data")

*// SQL statements can be run by using the sql methods provided by sqlContext.*
val results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name FROM data")
```

Adding data from all files is not a good idea as all the data will be loaded to memory. going one file at a time will be a better way.

But again depending on your use case, if you need data from all files you will need to append the rdds somehow.

Hope that answers your question!
Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Spark SQL can do this using the "toDF" method

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection

In your case:

```
case class Data(text: String, code: Float)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
// this is used to implicitly convert an RDD to a DataFrame.
import sqlContext.implicits._

val data = sc.textFile("data")
val dataFrame = data.map(d => Data(d._1, d._2._foFloat)).toDF()
```